# what does it say on this karate belt?

Tags: translation

[image]

I know it says "karate do" in the middle. what about first two and the last

I get "karate do" from this reference 
http://isami-eng.com/images/example/b/e4.html

Please! anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know it says "karate do" in the middle.

No, it does not.

It says:

> [国際]{こくさい}[空手]{からて}[連盟]{れんめい}

"Do" is「道」.  This one is 「連」.

Comment: "International Karate Federation"
good enough answer for me. thank you!